# Ошибка в findViewById

Tags: xml, eclipse, android, интерфейс, java

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

---

Подчёркивает id, говорит, что нет его в R,

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

В R его реально нет, а в Layout/main.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="* X"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" +"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="* X +"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= 0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="X"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView03"
        android:text=" = "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />







    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/X1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView05"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="X"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:text=" = "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />






    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/X2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ответ" />

</LinearLayout>
```

кнопка есть, Ctrl + S нажал, проект пересоздал, всё равно одна и та же ошибка...

Comment: Вообще советую создать отдельный файл с id, например ids.xml
А R.java может не обновиться из-за каких-то других ошибок в проекте

Comment: Отдельный файл с id?!
В таких случаях `Clear` проекта и искать ошибку в файлах xml.

Comment: - Проект - 3 поля и кнопка, какие ошибки XD
 - Как сделать этот файл??

Comment: @monomi а что Вас удивляет?

@niki-timofe все-таки my_button или button1? И можешь показать весь файл разметки?

Comment: @rasmisha button1

Comment: @niki-timofe
создаешь например ids.xml  в папке values

и дальше добавляешь строки в таком формате 

<item type="id" name="bCreate"></item>

В дальнешем используешь 

android:id="@id/bCreate"

Comment: У меня, кстати, все нормально добавилось. Может что-то поставилось криво?

Comment: @rasm 2 раза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно как-то все...

```
android:id="@+id/button1"

findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Все равно ты где-то накосячил =)
Но на будущее:

```
Button   
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  **android:onClick="response"**

    android:text="Ответ"
```

используй
в классе

```
public void response(View v) {
}
```

Comment: XD, ошибка не в этом, он до туда не доходит...

Comment: кинь полностью хмлку и не лезь в ер файл

Comment: у тебя тут других кнопок нету !!

Comment: В буфере строка была, я её сюда кинул, не посмотрел, что кнопка не та

Comment: Заработало, 3 раз проект пересоздал, и теперь без ошибки

Comment: @niki-timofe дальше мне там не дает комментировать. Руками не изменял R.java? В манифесте как я понял тоже ничего не менял? И в Activity нет ошибок больше?

Answer (score 1):

У меня в Эклипс тоже систематически происходит то же самое. В подсказке предлагают создать id в R и я соглашаюсь. Не знаю, правильно ли это, но всё после этого работает.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/854944)

Comment: Почему это не является ответом на вопрос, если помогает?

Comment: как минимум по причинам: 1. Вопрос был задан 11 лет назад 2. Его актуальность давно прошла ибо 3. Под вопросом был дан ответ, который принят в качестве решения

Comment: 1. Пока есть Эклипс, этот вопрос актуален.

Comment: 2.Лично я искала на него ответ месяц назад и нашла только в англоязычном stackoverflow. Уверена, что таких как я много. 3. Это в данном коде ошибка. Но и без всяких ошибок Эклипс систематически пишет, что id нету в R, и его там нету, хотя он есть в макете.